# Filtering multidimensional arrays by non-equal values to exclude duplicated records

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates, substr

Below are two arrays from two different feeds, they share different ids. Because of this, I have to rely on 'BriefTitle': I can tell by the 'BriefTitle' and other data (eg  [LocationCountry], [StartDate], [Condition]) that this is same record.  I would like to take substr of 'BriefTitle' to compare it to other 'BriefTitle' records to filter out duplicates, since they are contained in each other.  I am not looking for an exact match, which is what I've been finding for most solutions here.

I like the short solution proposed by sevavietl/ mickmackusa: 
[php remove duplicates from multidimensional array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577258/php-remove-duplicates-from-multidimensional-array-by-value)

```
$result = array_reverse(array_values(array_column(
    array_reverse($data),
    null,
    'BriefTitle'
)));
```

however, my 'BriefTitle' is an array (doesn't seem to work with array_column), and I am not sure how to apply substr function to the solution above.

Some quick notes:

- Fortunately, [BriefTitle][0] is always the value to compare
- If possible, I would like just grab the first instance for the data set, rejecting any following duplicates.

Any thoughts how I should approach this? The arrays:

```
 [0] => Array
        (
            [Rank] => 422
            [id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 152091
                )

            [Condition] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Depression
                    [1] => Ketamine
                )

            [BriefTitle] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Positron Emission Tomography Assessment of Ketamine Binding of the Serotonin Transporter
                )

            [LocationCountry] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Austria
                )

            [StartDate] => Array
                (
                    [0] => May 5, 2016
                )

            [LastUpdatePostDate] => Array
                (
                    [0] => October 15, 2018
                )

            [Entheogen] => ketamine
            [Source] => clinicaltrials.gov
        )   


    [1] => Array
        (
            [Rank] => 6673
            [id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => YSBSZ18291
                )

            [Condition] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Depressive Disorder
                    [1] => Ketamine
                )

            [BriefTitle] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Positron Emission Tomography assessment of Ketamine Binding of the Serotonin Transporter and its Relevance for Rapid Antidepressant Response
                    [1] => Die Rolle des Serotonintransporters bei der akuten antidepressiven Wirkung von Ketamin, untersucht mit Positronen-Emissions-Tomographie
                )

            [LocationCountry] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Austria
                )

            [StartDate] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2016 05 01
                )

            [LastUpdatePostDate] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2018 10 15
                )

            [Entheogen] => ketamine
            [Source] => clinicaltrialsregister.eu
        )
```

Comment: Your input data appears to be two separate arrays, not one. Also, there are no similarities in the `BriefTitle` array, so no de-duplicating required. To get an answer to your question, you need to show data which actually has to be changed, and also show what the data should look like afterwards.

Comment: Hi Nick,  thanks for the quick reply: 
1. Fixed,  error on my part.  
  
2. No data changed. Need these to non-duplicated based on a partial match (character limits keep me for posting more here).   

`[0] => Positron Emission Tomography Assessment of Ketamine Binding of the Serotonin Transporter`  
    

`[0] => Positron Emission Tomography assessment of Ketamine Binding of the Serotonin Transporter and its Relevance for Rapid Antidepressant Response`

Comment: (apologies for shoddy formatting, I am figuring out the markdown here)

Comment: Thanks for the update - so how do you decide what is a match?

Comment: Hi Nick - quick background. This is from merged data for 2 different clinical study databases. What I noticed is that some are duplicate: the title gives it away - one title is shorter than the other (country/conditions also help confirm this). The [BriefTitle] shares the most unique common element, even though its not an exact match.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: So is a matching title *always* just a substring of another? If so, which do you want to keep.

Comment: yes, in this case, always. I'd like to keep the first record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately because of the nature of your data (strings which match may be substrings of others, with different case) the only real option is to brute-force this. Loop over the array, storing titles as you go and checking whether the current title matches any of them:

```
$result = array();
$brieftitles = array();
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    $foundtitle = false;
    $title = $arr['BriefTitle'][0];
    foreach ($brieftitles as $btitle) {
        $foundtitle = (stripos($title, $btitle) !== false) || (stripos($btitle, $title) !== false);
        if ($foundtitle) break;
    }
    if (!$foundtitle) {
        $result[] = $arr;
        $brieftitles[] = $arr['BriefTitle'][0];
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/HMfdH)