# Remove Duplicate Nested Arrays From Multidimenssional Array By Nested Array Key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-filter, array-unique

I am trying to create an array where I need to filter with a certain key (`fileid`) so that it returns only unique keys for parent array. Here is what I have..

```
Array
(
    [ABCD] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [fileid] => 5454554
                    [filename] => myfile1.txt
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [fileid] => 5454954
                    [filename] => myfile2.txt
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [fileid] => 5454554
                    [filename] => myfile1.txt
                )

        )

    [EFGH] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [fileid] => 5429654
                    [filename] => myfile2.txt
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [fileid] => 5433954
                    [filename] => myfile2.txt
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [fileid] => 5429654
                    [filename] => myfile1.txt
                )

        )

)
```

The first keys (`ABCD` and `EFGH`) are File Owner IDs. The nested arrays contains the File ID and the FIle Name. I need to filter it so that every duplicate nested array (having same fileid) is removed.

I tried this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/946300/1954949) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42578062/1954949) and many other solutions found on the web. But no luck. I also tried

```
$result =  array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $file_array)));
```

No Luck again. Can someone please guide me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `array_map` and `array_filter` like so:

```
array_map(
    function($arr) {
        $exists = [];
        return array_values(
            array_filter(
                $arr,
                function($arr1) use (&$exists) {
                    if (isset($exists[$arr1['fileid']])) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    $exists[$arr1['fileid']] = true;
                    return true;
                }
            )
        );
    },
    $file_array,
);
```

Note: I used `array_values` to ensure the resultant array has consecutive numerical keys. If you want to keep the original numerical keys then it can be omitted.

Comment: Giving me an error :( 

PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in /home/aMlGCD/prog.php on line 57 (which is the closing of `array_map`.

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using? It works fine for me. Most likely you're using an older version of PHP and you need to remove the trailing commas.

Comment: PHP 7.3 (Which is the latest on my server).

Answer (score 2):

A simple couple of loops where you remember the fileid's that you have seen in the inner array. If you see a fileid twice, you unset that occurance of the array.
Note using `&$owners` in the outer loop so you can actually remove an occurance from within the foreach loop

```
$input = [  'ABCD' => [
                    ['fileid' => 5454554, 'filename' => 'myfile1.txt'],
                    ['fileid' => 5454954, 'filename' => 'myfile2.txt'],
                    ['fileid' => 5454554, 'filename' => 'myfile1.txt']
                    ],
            'EFGH' => [
                    ['fileid' => 5429654, 'filename' => 'myfile2.txt'],
                    ['fileid' => 5433954, 'filename' => 'myfile2.txt'],
                    ['fileid' => 5429654, 'filename' => 'myfile1.txt']
            ]
];
foreach ($input as &$owners){
    $ids = [];
    foreach($owners as $i=>$file){
        if ( in_array($file['fileid'], $ids) ){
            unset($owners[$i]);
        } else {
            $ids[] = $file['fileid'];
        }
    }
}
print_r($input);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [ABCD] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                ( [fileid] => 5454554, [filename] => myfile1.txt )

            [1] => Array
                ( [fileid] => 5454954, [filename] => myfile2.txt )
        )
    [EFGH] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                ( [fileid] => 5429654, [filename] => myfile2.txt )

            [1] => Array
                ( [fileid] => 5433954,  [filename] => myfile2.txt )
        )
)
```

**OR**

Build a new array containing only the non duplicated files

```
$input = [  'ABCD' => [
                    ['fileid' => 5454554, 'filename' => 'myfile1.txt'],
                    ['fileid' => 5454954, 'filename' => 'myfile2.txt'],
                    ['fileid' => 5454554, 'filename' => 'myfile1.txt']
                    ],
            'EFGH' => [
                    ['fileid' => 5429654, 'filename' => 'myfile2.txt'],
                    ['fileid' => 5433954, 'filename' => 'myfile2.txt'],
                    ['fileid' => 5429654, 'filename' => 'myfile1.txt']
            ]
];
$new = [];
foreach ($input as $owner => $files){
    $t = [];
    $ids = [];

    foreach($files as $i=>$file){
        if ( ! in_array($file['fileid'], $ids) ){
            $t[] = $file;
            $ids[] = $file['fileid'];
        }
    }
    $new[$owner] = $t;
}
print_r($new);
```